# WCF callback in new instance c#

Tags: c#, wcf, instancecontextmode

ive been working on a launcher using wcf to communicate with a server to kick users off when an update is needed.

so far its all working except for when there is a chain of functions from clients to server and back to clients, it SEEMS like the callbacks are in new instances on seperate threads meaning that the callbacks cannot be reflected in the GUI layer.

i want to know how to make it callback to the same instance of the client launcher as it started with, im storing the interface for the callback in a class to use when calling back to a particular client.

What I think is hapenning:

[image]

What I would like to be hapenning:

[image]